# Iterating over frames for dropping columns

Tags: python, pandas

The following for-loop iterating over two data frames doesn't work:

```
for frame in [df_train, df_test]:
    frame = frame.drop('Embarked', axis=1)
```

I don't get an error message, but the column 'Embarked' is not dropped in the two data frames. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help(frame.drop)`:

```
def drop(self, labels, axis=0, level=None, inplace=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Return new object with labels in requested axis removed

    ...

    inplace : bool, default False
        If True, do operation inplace and return None.
```

Right now, you're simply making new objects and naming them `frame`, which doesn't affect anything in your list.  You could use `inplace=True` to affect the original object instead:

```
for frame in [df_train, df_test]:
    frame.drop('Embarked', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I had pandas 0.12.0 where drop() apparently doesn't have the inplace option. I updated to 0.13.0 and it works fine now.

Comment: What can I do if I have several DataFrames and I want to apply the same set of operations to each with operations that do not support `inplace=True`? Is there a way to change the original DataFrame in a for-loop? For example, instead of `df_train[df_train > 1] = 1` and `df_test[df_test > 1] = 1` iterating over the two frames and changing the content of the DataFrames in the for-loop.

Comment: @ta.ft: usually different questions should be opened as new questions.  Makes it easier for other people to find the question, both for people to want to help and for other people who have the same question.

Comment: Sorry, now asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462394/iterating-over-dataframes).