# Iterating over DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to change a DataFrame in a for-loop? For example, instead of:

```
df_train[df_train > 1] = 1
df_test[df_test > 1] = 1
```

something like:

```
for frame in [df_train, df_test]:
    frame = frame[frame > 1] = 1
```

In this version the original DataFrames are not changed. How can I achieve that with a for-loop?

Answer (score 3):

In the following line, remove `frame =`:

```
frame = frame[frame > 1] = 1
#^^^^^^^
```

---

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df_train = pd.DataFrame([0.1, 0.2, 3], columns=['a'])
>>> df_test = pd.DataFrame([0.1, 5, 0.3], columns=['a'])
>>> df_train[df_train > 1] = 1
>>> df_test[df_test > 1] = 1
>>> for frame in [df_train, df_test]:
...     frame[frame > 1] = 1
... 
>>> df_train
     a
0  0.1
1  0.2
2  1.0
>>> df_test
     a
0  0.1
1  1.0
2  0.3
```